# Veifying if the given function is a norm or not

Tags: real-analysis

Let $X=C^1[0,1]$ be the space of continuous functions whose first derivatives are continuous on $[0,1]$. Define, $\Vert f\Vert_{_{\infty}}=\max\{|f(x)|:\ x \in [0,1]\}$, and $$ \Vert f\Vert_{_{A}}=\Vert f\Vert_{_{\infty}},\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Vert f\Vert_{_{B}}=\Vert f'\Vert_{_{\infty}}, \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \Vert f\Vert_{_{C}}=\Vert f\Vert_{_{\infty}}+\Vert f'\Vert_{_{\infty}}$$

(a)Which one of these is a norm on $X$.

(b) For which definition is the resulting normed linear space complete?

(a)

1) Clearly $\Vert f \Vert_{_{A}}$ is a norm.

2) I think the constant function causes a problem here since its derivative is zero which means $\Vert f \Vert_{B} =0$ for some $f \neq 0$ continuous on $[0,1]?$ is my argument true?

(3) I would say it is a norm since the axioms are achieved.

b)

1) I proved it is complete.

2), 3) I am not sure which way to start with, a prove or a counterexample shows the oppisite.

Thanks for any help

Comment: You’re right about 2), it’s not a norm, so (b) doesn’t apply. 1) doesn’t make $X$ complete actually. Think of a sequence of polynomials converging uniformly to $\sqrt{x}$.

Comment: I see. So no one of them are complete normed linear space.

Comment: Actually, you are wrong again. 3. makes $X$ a complete normed space.